# Browser has to be resized in order for code to work?

Tags: jquery, html, css, browser, resize

I am coding using mainly html and css with a bit of jquery for a parallax scroll. Whenever I save the code and refresh my browser some of the elements don't load and I have to pull the sides of the browser a bit to make everything load and fit together. I don't even know how to start troubleshooting this... All feedback is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: start by posting sample code ;) Read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Share with us your code that you have tried so far?

Comment: Okay so I have a lot of code... Like one html, two css, and I think three js files. I didn't write the js and I was told that's probably where the problem is, I just don't know how to read and figure out java. Should I post it all here?

Answer (score 0):

Without your current script I am not sure if you have tried using a container yet. 
If you would like to set your window to a standard size without having to resize the container will allow you to add a scroll bar within the window and

Option 1 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ2e/38/)

```
html,body {
overflow: auto;
}

.container {
width: 1100px;
}
```

Alternatively you can also try setting a container and further limiting your contents.

Option 2 [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ2e/39/)

```
html,body {
overflow: auto;
}

.container {
width: 900px;
}

.contents {
border: 2px solid blue;
height: 350px;
width: 500px;
}
```